# How can I make a MySQL SUM query return zero instead of null if there are no records?

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is my select query:

```
SELECT SUM(rating) AS this_week 
FROM table_name 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800)
```

Which basically counts the rating of an item for the last week (604800 is a number of seconds in 1 week).

The problem is that when there are no rows in the table, the this_week will be returned as NULL. I would like the query to return 0 in case there are no rows in the table. How to do it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rating),0) AS this_week FROM table_name 
  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800)
```

COALESCE is a function that will return the first non NULL value from the list.

Answer (score 37):

Can't you use `IFNULL(SUM(rating), 0)`?

Comment: This solution suits better than the accepted answer when using CI active records. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try this one :
SUM(IFNULL(rating, 0))

Comment: This question has had well-rated answers for a very long time. Please [edit] and explain why this is better than existing ones.