# How do I get SUM function in MySQL to return '0' if no values are found?

Tags: mysql, function, null, sum

Say I have a simple function in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(Column_1)
FROM Table
WHERE Column_2 = 'Test'
```

If no entries in `Column_`2 contain the text 'Test' then this function returns `NULL`, while I would like it to return 0.

I'm aware that a similar question has been asked a few times here, but I haven't been able to adapt the answers to my purposes, so I'd be grateful for some help to get this sorted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with MySQL SUM()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318640/help-with-mysql-sum)

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to avoid that outcome.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(column),0)
FROM   table
WHERE  ...
```

To see it in action, please see this sql fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1542/3/0

---

More Information:

Given three tables (one with all numbers, one with all nulls, and one with a mixture):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb270/4)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val   INT
);

INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES
(null),(1),(null),(2),(null),(3),(null),(4),(null),(5),(null),(6),(null);

CREATE TABLE bar
(
  id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val   INT
);

INSERT INTO bar (val) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

CREATE TABLE baz
(
  id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val   INT
);

INSERT INTO baz (val) VALUES
(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  'foo'                   as table_name,
        'mixed null/non-null'   as description,
        21                      as expected_sum,
        COALESCE(SUM(val), 0)   as actual_sum
FROM    foo
UNION ALL

SELECT  'bar'                   as table_name,
        'all non-null'          as description,
        21                      as expected_sum,
        COALESCE(SUM(val), 0)   as actual_sum
FROM    bar
UNION ALL

SELECT  'baz'                   as table_name,
        'all null'              as description,
        0                       as expected_sum,
        COALESCE(SUM(val), 0)   as actual_sum
FROM    baz
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb270/4/0)**:

```
| TABLE_NAME |         DESCRIPTION | EXPECTED_SUM | ACTUAL_SUM |
|------------|---------------------|--------------|------------|
|        foo | mixed null/non-null |           21 |         21 |
|        bar |        all non-null |           21 |         21 |
|        baz |            all null |            0 |          0 |
```

Comment: Isn't SELECT SUM(IFNULL(column,0)) FROM table GROUP BY something more correct? What if we have some IS NULL values and some real values in "column"?

Comment: @DarkSide: [Absolutely nothing](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad735/1/0) unexpected.

Comment: @BradChristie yes you're absolutely right. SUM works fine with NULL values too.

Comment: Please be aware that while`SUM` does function as desired, `AVG` and `COUNT` can [produce different results](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09dcb9/15) when receiving `NULL` Prompting you to use `COALESCE` as suggested by @DarkSide, depending on your desired outcome.

Comment: @fyrye depends on what you're after, absolutely. But so will any function that relies on a count of values over a broad summation.

Answer (score 83):

Use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Column1), 0) AS total FROM...

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Column1), 0) AS total FROM...
```

The difference between them is that `IFNULL` is a MySQL extension that takes two arguments, and `COALESCE` is a standard SQL function that can take one or more arguments. When you only have two arguments using `IFNULL` is  slightly faster, though here the difference is insignificant since it is only called once.

Comment: @Mark what is difference b/w  `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` ?? could you explain it ??

Comment: PS. For anyone working with Postgres, it supports only ```coalesce```.

Answer (score 6):

Can't get exactly what you are asking but if you are using an aggregate SUM function which implies that you are grouping the table.

The query goes for MYSQL like this

```
Select IFNULL(SUM(COLUMN1),0) as total from mytable group by condition
```

Comment: You group by condition but don't return it (you will get a bunch of amounts of unknown conditions) ?

Answer (score 0):

**if sum of column is 0 then display empty**

```
select if(sum(column)>0,sum(column),'')
from table
```