# MySQL sum of each column AND sum of all colums

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm putting together a simple answer tracking app that outputs bar graphs which shows how many people have answered each question.

```
a_id    q_id    a_option_1  a_option_2  a_option_3  a_option_4
1       1       NULL        NULL        1           NULL
2       1       NULL        1           NULL        NULL
3       1       1           NULL        NULL        NULL
4       1       1           NULL        NULL        NULL
5       2       NULL        1           NULL        NULL
6       2       1           NULL        NULL        NULL
7       2       1           NULL        NULL        NULL
8       2       1           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

For each chart, I'm doing:

```
SELECT sum(a_option_1) as a_1, sum(a_option_2) as a_2, sum(a_option_3) as a_3, sum(a_option_4) as a_4, sum(a_option_1) + sum(a_option_2) + sum(a_option_3) + sum(a_option_4) as total FROM interactive_answers WHERE q_id = x
```

That works fine if each option has an answer but

```
sum(a_option_1) + sum(a_option_2) + sum(a_option_3) + sum(a_option_4) as total
```

doesn't output anything if some of the options don't have a value.

What do I need to do to account for that?

Comment: First blush, use COALESCE, like: SUM(COALESCE(a_option_1, 0)).  COALESCE returns the first non-null argument, which will inject defined numbers into your equation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get SUM function in MySQL to return '0' if no values are found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602271/how-do-i-get-sum-function-in-mysql-to-return-0-if-no-values-are-found)

Comment: or use `IFNULL(fieldname, 0)` to return zero into the sum instead of null (which breaks it)

Comment: Coalesce is doing the job for me. Not sure whether this question needs to be closed as a duplicate or whether someone wants to answer and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just put an answer in.  I'll add some details to make it more than a duplicate.

Choose either:

```
SUM(COALESCE(a_option_1, 0))
```

or

```
COALESCE(SUM(a_option_1), 0)
```

I prefer the first form, though, largely because, well, that's how I think -- I think put "coalesce as close to the null as possible."  I'm not sure if it has a performance issue.

Also, IFNULL will get it done too like COALESCE.  IFNULL is faster, but only takes two arguments, as it's optimized for that single case.  I think I always use COALESCE because it works on any number of arguments, so it's more general and easier for me to remember as such.