# SQL query return a result on group by expression (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following query, I get a sum of amount per accounting period. However in some accounting periods, I do not have any amount, so naturally, those periods with no sum of amount (null) are not shown in the result set.

I would like to know how to return those with the sum of amount 0 for them.

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
    SUM(RESOURCE_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL,
FROM 
    RESOURCE_TBL
GROUP BY
    ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
```

I get the following result set

```
accounting_period   TOTAL
-------------------------
1                   234
3                    65
5                   943
6                   299
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
```

In the above period 2 and 4 is left out since the sum is zero or null but I would like to get

```
accounting_period   TOTAL
-------------------------
1                   234
2                     0
3                    65
4                     0
5                   943
6                   299
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
```

Comment: Outer join with a table having all possible months.

Comment: Does the above mean that periods 2 and 4 have rows in RESOURCE_TBL with a value of NULL for RESOURCE_AMOUNT or that they do not have rows at all?

Comment: @toonice  - it means no rows at all. If there were rows with NULL in them, then the result would have rows for those accounting periods, with the sum shown as NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a list of all the possible accounting periods and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that with your table:

```
WITH accounting_periods ( accounting_period ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT a.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
       COALESCE( SUM(RESOURCE_AMOUNT), 0 ) AS TOTAL
FROM   accounting_periods a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       RESOURCE_TBL r
       ON ( a.accounting_period = r.accounting_period )
GROUP BY a.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the article [How do I get SUM function in MySQL to return '0' if no values are found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602271/how-do-i-get-sum-function-in-mysql-to-return-0-if-no-values-are-found), please try the following...

```
SELECT ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,
       COALESCE( SUM(RESOURCE_AMOUNT), 0 ) AS TOTAL
FROM RESOURCE_TBL
GROUP BY ACCOUNTING_PERIOD;
```

Comment: This will not get a zero value for an accounting period if there are no rows in the table with that accounting period.

Comment: The phrase jax used of "those periods with no sum of amount (null)" suggested to me that RESOURCE_TBL does indeed have rows for such accounting periods with NULL being the value of RESOURCE_AMOUNT.  I shall ask Jax to clarify.

Comment: At the time I posted the question I was not sure if the table had rows with all accounting periods.