# MySQL return 0 if table doesn't have specific entry

Tags: mysql

Wasn't sure how to word my question, so sorry if it's a little confusing. Hopefully the below will clear it up a bit.

Here's the query I'm running so far:

```
select business.name, ifnull(sum(checkin.count),0) as checknum from checkin inner join business on business.id = checkin.business_id where business.state = 'NY' group by business.name order by checknum desc;
```

and it *almost* works as intended. There is one more business in NY, which doesn't have any counts in the checkin table, but I can't get it to output.

This is my current output:

`+---------------------------------------+----------+
| name                                  | checknum |
+---------------------------------------+----------+
| Lakeside Coffee                       |       31 |
| McDonalds                             |       18 |
| Valero                                |       15 |
| Angelo's Pizza & Grill                |       13 |
| Gino's Pizza                          |        8 |
| Sandy's Deli                          |        7 |
| Tribeca North Luxury Apartments Homes |        2 |
| Matt & Nat                            |        2 |
| Filion's Diner                        |        2 |
| Squirrel's Nest Restaurant and Bar    |        2 |
| Best Friends Family Diner             |        1 |
| China Buffet                          |        1 |
| Sandi's Kountry Kitchen               |        1 |
| Dick's Country Store                  |        1 |
+---------------------------------------+----------+`

But I need to capture the last business that doesn't have any checkins. Not sure how to tackle this further.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602271/how-do-i-get-sum-function-in-mysql-to-return-0-if-no-values-are-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)

Comment: thanks for that @isaace I wasn't sure how to search my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `right join` instead of `inner join`.

Left join will return all rows on the right side of the relationship regardless of whether any key on the left side matches.

Comment: thanks for the input! I actually need to do a `right join` since the business table has the extra business and is being joined in, right?

Comment: Just a suggestion though, it's a fairly common convention to start with the parent table and use left joins. Makes things easier to read/follow.