# Comparing sum of two subqueries inside select in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, query-builder

I'm bit a new for Yii2 and got confused ..
I have two subqueries

`$paidForOrder = (new Query())->select(['sum(amount*flow)'])->from('moneyflow')->where('order_uid = i.uid');`

`$orderAmount = (new Query())->select(['sum(sale_price*qty*flow)'])->from('salesflow')->where('order_uid = i.uid');`

NOTE: `$paidForOrder` can be false if nothing found in DB

My main query is to select all orders for customer where `$paidForOrder` is less than `$orderAmount`:

```
$Query =(new Query())
    ->select([
        'i.uid as uid',
        'i.created as created',
        'i.ordernum as ordernum',
        'order_amount' => $orderAmount,
        'paid_for_order' => $paidForOrder,
    ])
    ->from('orders i')
    ->leftJoin('salesflow s','i.uid = s.order_uid')
    ->where(['i.type_id' => 2, 'i.customer_id' => $customer_id])
    ->andWhere('<',$orderAmount,$paidForOrder)
    ->groupBy('i.uid')
    ->all();
```

Again note that last `$Query` returns order_amount and paid_for_order correctly
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

found solution finally,
there should be `->andFilterCompare($paidForOrder,$orderAmount,'<')` instead of `->andWhere('<',$orderAmount,$paidForOrder)`

but still it can't be executed if paid_for_order is false
UPD: thanks to this post [How can I make a MySQL SUM query return zero instead of null if there are no records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318640)